# Creating a single number from a numpy array - Python

Tags: machine-learning, python, dataset, k-nn, csv

I am working on a gender classification project. I am extracting the pixels of an image using a Numpy array in Python, similar to the one below:

```
[[[129 155 191] [123 150 185] [120 149 183]]
```

How can I use these values to extract a single meaningful number to be used in a csv file for K-Nearest Neighbor Algorithm. For example single number like

`0.34232`

In summary, how can I turn `[[[129 155 191] [123 150 185] [120 149 183]]` into a single number like `0.34232`

Comment: I don't think you have to shrink the dimension of your data for using KNN! You have to keep that information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Data Science! You're question needs a little more detail... there are many many ways to make an array into a single number. You should say a little more about what you mean by **meaningful**.

Here are a few examples, using your example array, which may seem outrageously simple, but do indeed form the basis to many of the techniques used in modern research:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: x = np.array([[129, 155, 191], [123, 150, 185], [120, 149, 183]], dtype=np.float32)

In [3]: x
Out[3]: 
array([[129., 155., 191.],
       [123., 150., 185.],
       [120., 149., 183.]], dtype=float32)
```

Now here are a few (randomly selected) ways to create a single number from your array:

```
In [4]: np.mean(x)    # the mean / average
Out[4]: 153.88889

In [5]: np.sum(x)    # the sum
Out[5]: 1385.0

In [6]: np.std(x)    # the standard deviation
Out[6]: 25.722641

In [7]: np.linalg.norm(x)    # the Frobius norm - a distance measure
Out[7]: 468.07156

In [8]: np.max(x)
Out[8]: 191.0
```

These might seem stupidly simple, but if we were to treat your array as a single block from a larger image-array, then these might represent *pooling-layers* that are used to down-sample arrays as they are passed through a neural network. Just have a look at the available [**pooling layers within the Keras library**](https://keras.io/api/layers/pooling_layers/).

Which method you might want to use will heavily depend on your use case, your dataset and your model.